# Округление вверх по итерируемому объекту

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть итерируемый объект, в котором элементы отсортированны и уникальны. Для простоты такой кортеж:

```
c = (1,3,7,12,17)
```

И некое натуральное число `n`.
Нужно, как в операции округления вверх, получить элемент кортежа, который либо равен этому числу, либо является ближайшим следующим числом. (Если `n` больше последнего элемента, то следует возвращать последний элемент)
Моё решение таково:

```
def closest_next(itrbl, n):
    itrtr = iter(itrbl)
    nn = next(itrtr)
    while n > nn:
        try:
            nn = next(itrtr)
        except StopIteration:
            return nn
    return nn
```

Для:

```
for _ in range(1,19):
    print(_ , closest_next(c,_))
```

Должно выдавать:

```
1 1
2 3
3 3
4 7
5 7
6 7
7 7
8 12
9 12
10 12
11 12
12 12
13 17
14 17
15 17
16 17
17 17
18 17
```

Думаю мой вариант можно в раза 4 сократить, и сделать его O(logN).

Comment: так в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), который как раз и выполняет двоичный поиск в отсортированных данных.

```
>>> import bisect
>>> c = (1,3,7,12,17)
>>> c[min(len(c)-1, bisect.bisect_left(c, 0))]
1
>>> c[min(len(c)-1, bisect.bisect_left(c, 1))]
1
>>> c[min(len(c)-1, bisect.bisect_left(c, 5))]
7
>>> c[min(len(c)-1, bisect.bisect_left(c, 13))]
17
>>> c[min(len(c)-1, bisect.bisect_left(c, 20))]
17
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно сделать немного попроще вроде:

```
def closest_next(itrbl, n):
    for nn in itrbl:
        if n <= nn:
            break
    return nn
```

А если вы хотите именно скорость, а не простоту, то никаких итерейблов, тогда нужна готовая индексируемая отсортированная коллекция (список, кортеж) и искать в ней двоичным поиском нужный элемент, тогда будет `O(logN)`. А с итерейблом вам придётся перебирать элементы последовательно, пока не найдётся нужный и это будет порядка `O(N)` какой алгоритм ни возьми.

Comment: Ну так вот у меня есть "готовая индексируемая отсортированная коллекция (кортеж)", и тогда как этот т.н. двоичный поиск сделать?